# How to get all children data Inside a nested key Database in Firebase Realtime Database Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database structure as below.
[image]

I am able to retrieve the children's data when I give reference to date but I want to retrieve data without referencing to date but the previous nested key.

That is, when I write the following, I am able to get the data:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("LDC Wise").child("Agra").child("25-10-2022");
```

But when I write the following, I am getting null data:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("LDC Wise").child("Agra")
```

How do I go about fetching all the data in the next sublevel of the database without referencing to date key explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I go about fetching all the data in the next sublevel of the database without referencing to date key explicitly?

This can be solved by looping through the results twice:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference agraRef = db.child("LDC Wise").child("Agra");
agraRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot innerSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //Get the data out of the innerSnapshot object.
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey Darshan. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hey Alex, that's a great way to solve the issue and sorry for the delayed response. The laptop which I was working on is at office. I'll update you tomorrow soon.

Comment: Ok. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Hey Alex, it works! Awesome. Thanks a lot.
 I was able to fetch all the children data at once with the following line. 
 String value = String.valueOf(innerSnapshot.getValue(ClassName.class)); 

Now, moving on to filtering these data based on key! Haha.